# C++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (similar)

Tags: c++

I was using my mbp practicing random questions online when I encountered difficulties compiling my code.
I did search the net for similar problems but this is what I came up with and is still uncompilable.

I have error message

```
 c++     test.cpp   -o test 

 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
 "matrix::mSubtraction(float*, float*)", referenced from:
       _main in test-fb9462.o   "matrix::mMultiplication(float*, float*)", referenced from:
       _main in test-fb9462.o   "matrix::mShow(float*)", referenced from:
       _main in test-fb9462.o   "matrix::mAddition(float*, float*)", referenced from:
       _main in test-fb9462.o   "matrix::mDivision(float*, float*)", referenced from:
       _main in test-fb9462.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

---

### test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    float matrix_a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    float matrix_b[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    matrix m;

    m.Cols = 3;
    m.Rows = 3;

    cout <<  "Matrix A :\n";
    m.mShow((float *)matrix_a);
    cout << "Matrix B :\n";
    m.mShow((float *)matrix_b);

    cout << "Matrix Addition :\n";
    m.mAddition((float *)matrix_a,(float *)matrix_b);
    m.mShow((float *)m.ans);

    cout << "Matrix Subtraction :\n";
    m.mSubtraction((float *)matrix_a,(float *)matrix_b);
    m.mShow((float *)m.ans);

    cout << "Matrix Multiplication :\n";
    m.mMultiplication((float *)matrix_a,(float *)matrix_b);
    m.mShow((float *)m.ans);

    cout << "Matrix Division :\n";
    m.mDivision((float *)matrix_a,(float *)matrix_b);
    m.mShow((float *)m.ans);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

void matrix::mShow(float *A) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix::Cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix::Rows; j++) {
            printf("%f  \n",*((A+i*3)+j));
        }
    }
}

void matrix::mAddition(float *A, float *B) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix::Cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix::Rows; j++) {
            matrix::ans[i][j]= *((A+i*3) + j) + *((B+i*3) + j);
        }
    }
}

void matrix::mSubtraction(float *A, float *B) {
    cout << "After matrix addition" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix::Cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix::Rows; j++) {
            matrix::ans[i][j]= *((A+i*3) + j) - *((B+i*3) + j);
        }
    }
}

void matrix::mMultiplication(float *A, float *B) {
    cout << "After matrix addition" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix::Cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix::Rows; j++) {
            matrix::ans[i][j]= *((A+i*3) + j) * *((B+i*3) + j);
        }
    }
}

void matrix::mDivision(float *A, float *B) {
    cout << "After matrix addition" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix::Cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix::Rows; j++) {
            matrix::ans[i][j]= *((A+i*3) + j) / *((B+i*3) + j);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### matrix.h

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_H__
#define __MATRIX_H__
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class matrix {

private:

public:

    int Cols;
    int Rows;
    float ans[3][3];
    void mShow(float *);
    void mAddition(float *,float *);
    void mSubtraction(float *,float *);
    void mMultiplication(float *,float *);
    void mDivision(float *,float *a);

};

#endif
```

Thank you guys for kindly helping me out.

Comment: you'll want to show your `Makefile` as well, that's where the bug is

Answer (score 2):

```
c++ test.cpp -o test
```

This cannot work since you need to link the machine/object code of `matrix.cpp` as well. Try:

```
c++ -c matrix.cpp
c++ -c test.cpp
c++ -o test matrix.o test.o
```

Or, with appropriate options for you compiler.

Comment: yes this did work since I was used to using vs2017 before, I did not notice that I have to build each files separately or use makefile like Anthony mentioned